# Regarding the units of the shift produced by subsidies on supply curve

Tags: microeconomics, supply-and-demand

I am giving my first steps on microeconomics and I can't fully understand why by applying a **per unit subsidy**, the supply curve is shifted by a fixed amount. In wikipedia's words:

> Marginal subsidies on production will shift the supply curve to the right until the vertical distance between the two supply curves is equal to the **per unit subsidy**

But let's say that my supply curve is given by 
$$ Q_s = -200 +3 \cdot P $$ 
If a **per unit** subsidy is applied, the new supply curve is now given by:
$$ Q_s = -200 +3 \cdot (P+50) $$ 
But if the unit of the subsidy is $[\frac{\$}{units}] $ the units of the equation don't match: 
$$ Q_s [units] = -200[units] +3[\frac{units}{\$}] \cdot (P[\$]+50[\frac{\$}{units}]) $$ 
So shouldn't a **per unit** subsidy change the slope of the supply curve rather than shifting it?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The confusion stems from the fact that the price is also a $\frac{\$}{units}$